# How to overlay two numpy arrays/images conditionally

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Given 2 images/numpy arrays of same shape, for example:

- arrayA, shape = (100,100,3). Contains red, blue and black pixels.
- arrayB, shape = (100,100,3). Contains green, yellow and black pixels.

Now I would like to overlay arrayB on arrayA, with the conditions:
(arrayC = overlay arrayB on arrayA)

1. If the arrayA pixel value is red or blue, arrayC pixel = arrayA pixel color.
2. If the arrayA pixel is black, arrayC pixel = arrayB pixel color.

How can I do that in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Numpy:

```
red = [1, 0, 0]
blue = [0, 0, 1]
black = [0, 0, 0]
shape = (5, 5, 3)
arrayA = np.zeros(shape)
arrayA[1, 1, :] = red
arrayA[2, 2, :] = blue
arrayB = np.ones(shape)
arrayC = np.full(shape, np.nan)

# Change selected pixels according to condition 1
pixels_to_change = np.where(
    (arrayA == red).all(axis=2) | (arrayA == blue).all(axis=2)
)
arrayC[pixels_to_change] = arrayA[pixels_to_change]

# Change selected pixels according to condition 2
pixels_to_change = np.where((arrayA == black).all(axis=2))
arrayC[pixels_to_change] = arrayB[pixels_to_change]

# Test pixels
assert np.array_equal(arrayC[1, 1], red)
assert np.array_equal(arrayC[2, 2], blue)
assert np.array_equal(arrayC[0, 0], arrayB[0, 0])
```